# Extracting Sequential Pattern

Tags: awk, sequential

Can anyone help me on how to write a script to extract sequential lines?
I was able to find and get a script working to create all the permutations of the given inputs, but that's not what I need.

```
awk 'function perm(p,s,     i) {
       for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
         if(p==1)
           printf "%s%s\n",s,A[i]
         else
           perm(p-1,s A[i]", ")
     }
     {
       A[++n]=$1
     }
     END{
       perm(n)
     }' infile
```

Unfortunately, I don't understand the script well enough to made a modification (not due to lack of trying).
I need to extract 2 to 5 sequential lines/word patterns.

An illustration of what I need is as follows:

Eg.

inputfile.txt:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
```

outputfile.txt:

```
A B
B C
C D
D E
E F
F G
A B C
B C D
C D E
D E F
E F G
A B C D
B C D E
C D E F
D E F G
A B C D E
B C D E F
C D E F G
```

Comment: Is that C code? Does this have to be written using `awk`?

Comment: preferably written in a script. Just that the cleaning up of original data was done in awk, so i thought it would be nice to continue with awk.

Comment: "A script" is too generic. What programming language?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Python answer.

General algorithm:

- Load all letters into a list
- For n = 2..5, where n is size of the "window". You "slide" that window over the list and print those n characters.

Python is nice for this because of list slicing.

```
with open('input.txt') as f_in, open('output.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    chars = f_in.read().splitlines() 

    for n in range(2, 6):
        for start_window in range(len(chars) - n + 1):
            f_out.write(' '.join(chars[start_window:start_window + n]))
            f_out.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{n=1} 
      FNR==1{n++} 
            {a[c++]=$0; c=c%n} 
     FNR>n-1{for(i=c;i<c+n-1;i++) printf "%s ",a[i%n]; 
             print}' file{,,,}

1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
6 7
7 8
8 9
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
4 5 6
5 6 7
6 7 8
7 8 9
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6
4 5 6 7
5 6 7 8
6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 8
5 6 7 8 9
```

multiple scans of the input file (number of commas).  Used `seq 9` as the input file.

Answer (score 0):

Another in awk:

```
{ a[NR]=$0 }
END {
    o[0]=ORS
    for(i=2;i<=5;i++)
        for(j=1;j<=length(a);j++) {
            printf "%s%s", a[j], (++k==i?o[k=0]:OFS)
            if(!k&&j!=length(a)) j-=(i-1)
        }
}
```